# Censoring based on dependent variables of other subjects

Tags: panel-data, censoring

I understand that the Heckman approach can be used if the observation rule is static and thus can be estimated easily.

However, I have a panel where simply the largest $y$ among all individuals in each time period is not observed. I.e., my data looks like this:

```
y    t  ID  x1  x2   x3 ..
1.3  1  1   ..  ..
1.7  1  2   ..  ..
     1  3   ..  ..
2.1  2  1   ..  ..
1.9  2  2   ..  ..
     2  3   ..  ..
.. ....
```

Of course, I can easily estimate a lower bound for each missing observation (i.e., the largest other $y$ observed in this time period), but that would of course bias the estimates.

How can I correctly account for the missing $y$ observations (which need not always result from ID 3) ?

Comment: what type of analysis are you performing? Is there a rank based test that would work (since you know the missing value is highest rank)?

Comment: Well in the end I want to regress y on x.

Comment: I would use Bayesian framework. Specify a panel model(maybe a dynamic one), and do Gibbs sampling to draw missing y's and parameters.